# Creating 3rd array on the base of previous 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a 3rd array on the base of previous 2 arrays so that the first value of the new 3rd array is equal to the sum of the first values of 1st and 2nd arrays. I understand it something like this

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
array2 = [6,7,8,9,2];
array3 = [];

here goes the function /which I can't understand how to write/
array3[0] = array1[0] + array2[0]

console.log(array3);
```

Can you please help me? Sorry if this seems too primitive to you, I'm a beginner. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method

```js
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 2];
array3 = array1.map(function(v, i) {
  return v + array2[i];
});

console.log(array3);
```

---

Although simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) can be used

```js
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 2];
array3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  array3[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
}

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: OMG, it's that simple:) thank you very-very much! I chose the for loop option, I tried it, but because of putting [0] instead of [i] it gave errors. 
Now I see! Thank you again:)

Comment: before trying like you said)

Answer (score 1):

You try merge method for getting third array.

```
int array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
int array2 = [6,7,8,9,2]; 
int[]array3 = merge(array1,array2); // Merging two array and storing in third
```

and then print in for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<array3.length; i++){
  System.out.print(array3 [i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure length of array1 equal length of array2:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [6,7,8,9,2];
var array3 = [];

var length = array1.length || array2.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   array3.push(array1[i] + array2[i]);
}

console.log(array3);
```

Demo [Here!](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/KMPOeg?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you so much!